# Example of XMLRPC interface API with BUGZILLA

Tags: python, bugzilla, xmlrpclib, xmlrpcclient

How to access Bugzilla bugs with XMLRPC interface.
What .py and .XML contains.
 bugzilla server URL api methods

Comment: What results did you find on google?

Comment: @Danielle The result of google from my place gives the first five findings  of this exact question, couple more of unrelated stackoverflow Bugzilla questions, and point to Bugzilla documentation which is a path to go, although unpleasant path.

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow this, although it is not obvious/ Requires a lot of work to implement it: https://www.bugzilla.org/docs/5.0/en/html/integrating/api/Bugzilla/WebService/Server/XMLRPC.html